# Attempted to call an undefined method named "query" of class

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony, websocket

I working on a web socket app using ratchet and symfony 2.8 to connect to database and changing value in a certain column if someone connect to the server so I used this code to edit the query in the Chat.php file

```
$sql = $this->container->get('database_connection');
$users = $sql->query("UPDATE user SET onOroff= '1' WHERE UserId='2'");
```

but the proplem when I call it in `SocketCommand.php`

```
new Chat($this->getContainer())
```

I get this error

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "query" of class
```

the `chat.php` code

```
<?php
namespace check\roomsBundle\Sockets;
use tuto\testBundle\Entity\Users;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;

class Chat extends Controller implements MessageComponentInterface  {
    protected $container;
    protected $clients;

    //protected $em;

    //protected $db;
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container) {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
        $this->container = $container;

    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
        $sql = $this->container->get('database_connection');
        $users = $sql->query("UPDATE user SET onOroff= '1' WHERE UserId='2'");


    }


}
```

the `SocketCommand.php` full code

```
<?php
// myapplication/src/sandboxBundle/Command/SocketCommand.php
// Change the namespace according to your bundle
namespace check\roomsBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

// Include ratchet libs
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
// Change the namespace according to your bundle
use check\roomsBundle\Sockets\Chat;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
class SocketCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('sockets:start-chat')
            // the short description shown while running "php bin/console list"
            ->setHelp("Starts the chat socket demo")
            // the full command description shown when running the command with
            ->setDescription('Starts the chat socket demo')
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {

        $output->writeln([
            'Chat socket',// A line
            '============',// Another line
            'Starting chat, open your browser.',// Empty line
        ]);

        $server = IoServer::factory(
            new HttpServer(
                new WsServer(
                    new Chat($this->getContainer())
                )
            ),
            8080
        );

        $server->run();
    }
}
```

the services.yml code

```
services:
     database_connection:
         class: check\roomsBundle\Sockets\Chat
         arguments: ["@service_container"]
```

Comment: My gut says try capitalizing it $sql->Query()

Comment: @BrettHarris i tried but i still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
services:
     database_connection:
         class: check\roomsBundle\Sockets\Chat
         arguments: ["@service_container"]
```

So you defined a service with id: `database_connection` that represents your `Chat` class

```
$sql = $this->container->get('database_connection');
```

And inside the same `Chat` class you try to get that service from container to execute sql query on it?

Code you shared with us doesn't make sense. Take a closer look at your services definition.